# python Psycopg delete not working

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2

The code is below. It returns "DELETE 1" when there is a record to delete and "DELETE 0" when there isn't. But it doesn't actually delete the record when there is one there. The exact same SQL (with `%s` replaced with `tournament_id`) pasted into pgAdmin III deletes the record. I'm at the wood/trees stage. Any ideas?

```
def deletePlayers(tournamentId):
    # takes tournamentId and deletes all records from tournament_player 
    # with that tournamentId 
    # but not an error if no records to delete

    # check tournamentId set if not return
    if tournamentId < 1:
        returnStr = "ERROR - tournamentId not set"
        return returnStr

    DB = connect()
    cur = DB.cursor()

    # delete data
    SQL = "DELETE from tournament_player where tournament_id = %s;"
    data = (tournamentId,)
    cur.execute(SQL, data )
    returnStr = cur.statusmessage
    DB.commit
    # tidy up
    cur.close
    DB.close

    return returnStr
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is mostly unrelated to your database. To call a method in Python that has no arguments, add `()` to the end of it. This will call `commit` on your database:

```
DB.commit()
```

while this only gets a method reference:

```
DB.commit
```

So in your code, you didn't actually commit. (Or close, for that matter, but that's not necessary.)

Comment: Many thanks, this fixed it - I'll get a lithium top-up.